# visual studio 2013 .net 4.5 where about

Tags: .net

I installed visual studio 2013 ultimate and but when I check for visual studio 2013 folder in the program files folder, I did not see it.  In addition, I tried to find out the .net version 4.5 using regedit.exe, but all I see was v4.  Visual studio 2013 runs just fine.  Any idea?

Comment: VS2013 is located @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0

Comment: Here is the path for it:  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe".  Studio 2013 is in studio 2012.  That is weird.

Comment: You can also check in Add/Remove Programs to see if there is a 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1' listing.

Comment: .Net FX 4.5 is an inplace replacement for 4.0.  Meaning it will overwrite the files in the 4.0 framework directory.  Check out this blog post.  [Blog Post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NETVersioningAndMultiTargetingNET45IsAnInplaceUpgradeToNET40.aspx)

Comment: @bachdang It's not in Studio 2012, it's in VS 12.0. The version number is different from the year. VS 2010 = VS 10.0, VS 2012 = VS 11.0, VS 2013 = VS 12.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know where the program is installed, just right-click the desktop icon and click "Open file location"